# How to set the DataContext of a KeyBinding to a specific ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datacontext

This seems like such a basic question but after hours of searching around and not figuring out what I'm doing wrong I decided it's time to ask for help!

I'm new to WPF and the MVVM pattern, but am trying to create an application that has several windows you can navigate through by clicking buttons. This is accomplished by having the app window display UserControls using DataTemplates, so there's no content currently shared between pages (though there will be once I create the navigation area). Here's what the XAML looks like for the main window, with there currently only being one page in the application:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Application.ApplicationView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Application"
    Title="ApplicationView" Height="300" Width="300" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LoginMenuViewModel}">
        <local:LoginMenuView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


<DockPanel>
    <ContentControl
        Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
</DockPanel>
```

Now what I'd like to do is add a KeyBinding that reacts to the escape button being pressed. When this is done "LogoutCommand" should fire in the LoginMenuViewModel. I'm stuck getting the keybinding to trigger any commands within LoginMenuViewModel, and I've figured it's probably because the DataContext needs to be set to reference LoginMenuViewModel. For the life of me I can't get this to work.

Am I going about application-wide commands completely the wrong way? Is there some super simple fix that will make me smack my forehead in shame? Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know your ViewModel code, so it is not easy to give you details hints.
First of all, if your are using MVVM, you should have your own implementation of `ICommand` interface. You can find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute) the most common one (and a simple MVVM tutorial too).

After you have your own command class, your ViewModel should expose your `LogoutCommand`:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    /* ... */

    public ICommand LogoutCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return /* your command */
        }
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

In your code behind you will set: `DataContext = new ViewModel();` and at this point you can declare the KeyBindings that you need:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Escape" Command="{Binding Path=LogoutCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

In this way when the Window is active and the user press the "Esc" key, your LogoutCommand is executed.

This is a brief summary that I hope will guide you in deepening the MVVM and its command system.

Comment: Thanks for the response!


I have the ViewModel set up as you've described. From my understanding you can only set one DataContext per View, so what if I wanted to have the F1 key activate a command in a different ViewModel? If I set the DataContext to the second ViewModel after setting it to the first ViewModel won't it overwrite the first one?


I'd like to set the DataContext on a per-KeyBinding basis so that each KeyBinding can reference a command in different ViewModels.

Comment: First of all consider that a single ViewModel can expose more than one `ICommand` and `InputBindings` is a collection (so you can declare more KeyBindings). Anyway if you have more view models (for example ViewModel1, ViewModel2, ViewModel3) you can easly "group" them in a single view model which has got 3 readonly properties, one for each ViewModel. Then you will use: `DataContext = new GlobalViewModel();`

Comment: Creating a GlobalViewModel was the perfect solution, thank you!